# Regex to remove this string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I am scripting Agent Jobs using SMO for SQL Server and the resulting script strings have a have parameter and value that I want to remove from the final version I am storing.  The portion of the script that I want to look at is the schedule being added to the job, where it includes a @schedule_uid parameter with a GUID associated with it.  I'd like to remove this entirely from the script.

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name='Job Name', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=4, 
        @freq_subday_interval=10, 
        @freq_relative_interval=1, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20150119, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'a70709af-bce7-4c65-a4cd-7574acd31ca2'
```

The part that I want to replace is the following:

```
, \r\n\t\t@schedule_uid=N'a70709af-bce7-4c65-a4cd-7574acd31ca2'
```

So that the final string is:

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name='Job Name', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=4, 
        @freq_subday_interval=10, 
        @freq_relative_interval=1, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20150119, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959
```

I've tried various combinations of things I've been reading online but I can't seem to make it replace or even match.  I know that the regex for the guid matching is:

```
\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b'
```

I've tried to add this into a number of things, and thought that the following regex would work but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or missing

```
@", \r\n\t\t@schedule_uid=N'\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b'"
@", \r\n\t\t@schedule_uid=N'[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}'"
@", \r\n\t\t\b@schedule_uid=N'[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}'\b"
```

I'm not looking for a solution as much as I'd like to know what I'm missing. I've been reading the regular-expressions.info site for a while and I'm usually able to figure out the correct regex, but this has had me stumped for a few days now.

**EDIT:**

It's not always the last item and it's not guaranteed to only occur once within the script since a job can have multiple schedules which have different @schedule_uid's and I want to get rid of all of them without looping. This is why I chose Regex for the operation. It also needs to remove the comma at the end of the previous parameters line for the code to remain syntax correct.

Comment: why don't you just find `schedule_uid` in the string and remove the whole line?

Comment: I need to also remove the trailing comma before it on the previous line which is why the , \r\n\t\t are included in the regex.

Comment: Why regex? Why not just use normal string operations?

Comment: Are you sure there's a space after the comma?  why not just change the space to the regex whitespace marker so you don't ahve to care?  This works for me in regex Hero: `,\W+@schedule_uid=.*$`

Comment: It's just occurred to me that you might not be specifying the multiline matching option in your Regex matching code, which you will need since you're attempting to match across a carriage return.  The full documentation for Regex options, including the MultiLine you need is here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work for me and it will enable you to remove all the newlines, tabs etc:

```
(?:\n|\t|\r|.){1,3}.*\@sc.*'
```

You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/lO5rQ6/2)

Comment: OK, that works if I add a comma to the front so it replaces that as well, so now I guess I just need to go through each of the sequences and try to understand why it works the way it does on the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

@schedule_uid=N'[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}'

Created and tested using http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

A little more complicated, but works.

```
string test = "EXEC...";

var lines = test.Split(new char [] { ',' }).ToList();

lines = lines.Select((line, index) => 
{
  var indexof = line.IndexOf("@schedule_uid");
  if (indexof > -1)
  {
    if (index == 0)
    {
      return line.Substring(0, indexof);
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return line + ",";
})
.Where(line => line != null)
.ToList();

test = string.Join(string.Empty, lines);
```

[JsFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VCLo3t).

Comment: Because there is a lot more code behind the end of the schedule_uid parameter and I can't just trim it all off, and if there are multiple schedule_uid lines in the string I want to replace them correctly without looping.

Comment: That certainly made it a tad more difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as little as possible, just using basic string operations.

```
        string exec = ...

        int i = exec.IndexOf("@schedule_uid");

        while (i > -1)
        {
            int j = i;
            //Find the previous comma
            while (exec[i] != ',')
                i--;
            //Find the end, next line, or next comma
            while (j < exec.Length && exec[j] != '\r' && exec[j] != ',')
                j++;
            exec = exec.Remove(i, j - i);
            i = exec.IndexOf("@schedule_uid");
        }
```

I'm deliberately ignoring the no looping requirement, in favour of simple code that works. tested vs this...

```
        string exec = @"
        EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule, @schedule_uid=N'a70709af-bce7-4c65-a4cd-7574acd31ca2', @job_id=@jobId, @name='Job Name', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @freq_type=4, 
    @freq_interval=1, 
    @freq_subday_type=4, 
    @freq_subday_interval=10, 
    @freq_relative_interval=1, 
    @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
    @schedule_uid=N'a70709af-bce7-4c65-a4cd-7574acd31ca2', 
    @active_start_date=20150119, 
    @active_end_date=99991231, 
    @active_start_time=0, 
    @active_end_time=235959, 
    @schedule_uid=N'a70709af-bce7-4c65-a4cd-7574acd31ca2'";
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not simple or as efficient as the Regex code for this operation on larger script strings.  It only works out to System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, @",(?:\n|\t|\r|.){1,3}.*\@sc.*'", ""); once the regex is understood.

Comment: @JonathanKehayias. No need to apologise. I'd measure simplicity an efficiency as the amount of time it'll take me to debug when it's not working as I expect. Unless it's in a performance critical area and then I'd benchmark it and optimise it.